# Eclipse: Central p2 repository (where all Eclipse and 3rd parties plugins are)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, repository, p2, centralized

Where is Central p2 repository, that has all Eclipse and 3rd parties plugins ?

Comment: I heard, there was project to collect 3rd party plugins in one place.

Comment: p2's metadata model is more complex than Maven's model, so p2 repositories don't scale up that well. I've heard of an attempt to create a p2 repository with all content of Maven central, but that attempt failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All third-party plugins are available through the **[MarketPlace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/)**, and will reference all the p2 sites.

For Eclipse itself, you would see the list of p2 update sites for all Eclipse distros at the "[**Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites** page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites)".

There isn't just *one* p2 site which would reference everything, but the Marketplace automatically creates a combined update site with your own favorite plugins, if you create an account on the Eclipse Market Place website.

Comment: MarketPlace is actually index of p2 repositories. The problem with p2 repositories is that they can pop-up and go down, or be unavailable in this moment.

Comment: @PaulVerest but surely the p2 repos mentioned in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites for Eclipse itself are more stable?

Comment: @PaulVerest [Bananeweizen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/44089/bananeweizen) just made an interesting edit to the answer.

Comment: I confused with some Eclipse project, that was collecting used plugins into 1 repository. Yes, unfortunately, there is no Central p2 repository.